# How can I set the length of an edge in Maya via Python?

Tags: python, scale, maya

I have a number of edges with different lengths. I get the length of one of the edges and then want to scale a selection of edges to the gotten length. 
I get the length via this code: (Not my code btw: http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-846300.html)

```
global length
length =[]
sel=cmds.ls(sl=True,fl=True)
cmds.ConvertSelectionToVertices()
p=cmds.xform(sel,q=True,t=True,ws=True)
length=math.sqrt(math.pow(p[0]-p[3],2)+math.pow(p[1]-p[4],2)+math.pow(p[2]-p[5],2))
cmds.select(sel)
cmds.selectMode(co=True)
cmds.selectType(eg=True)
print 'Edge Length=',length
```

This scales all selected edges along the component axis y direction, which is how I want them to scale:

```
cmds.scale( 0,1,0, cs=True)
```

Now to set the length of an edge to the gotten length I've tried like this, but that doesn't work.

```
cmds.scale( length, cs=True)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: you lack some maths in there

Comment: Thanks. i figured as much. As i said tho, i have pretty much no idea what i am doing, so can you be more precise?

Comment: the scale lenght is an scalar value, you are transforming it through x,y,z components, so you need to know how much you need to scale it in each axis to get that desired lenght

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in case someone needs this working in the future. Here is the entire code

```
def getEdgeLengthFunc (*pArgs):
    global referenceLength
    referenceLength =[]
    sel1=cmds.ls(sl=True,fl=True)
    cmds.ConvertSelectionToVertices()
    p=cmds.xform(sel1,q=True,t=True,ws=True)
    referenceLength=math.sqrt(math.pow(p[0]-p[3],2)+math.pow(p[1]-p[4],2)+math.pow(p[2]-p[5],2))
    cmds.select(sel1)
    cmds.selectMode(co=True)
    cmds.selectType(eg=True)

def setEdgeLengthFunc (*pArgs):
    sel2=cmds.ls(sl=True,fl=True)
    cmds.ConvertSelectionToVertices()
    p=cmds.xform(sel2,q=True,t=True,ws=True)
    initialLength=math.sqrt(math.pow(p[0]-p[3],2)+math.pow(p[1]-p[4],2)+math.pow(p[2]-p[5],2))
    cmds.select(sel2)
    cmds.selectMode(co=True)
    cmds.selectType(eg=True)
    lengthToSet=abs(referenceLength / initialLength)

    cmds.scale( 1, lengthToSet, 1, cs=True, a=True)
```